# Escape apostrophes in dynamic strings using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, razor, pdf.js, pdfobject

I have a list of file names that are being dynamically generated using .NET's `Directory.Enumerate`. When ever I try to view a file that includes an apostrophe and try to render it the string is cut off at the `'`. I tried using string.replace but its not helping. One example is `\\shared_directory\PDFs\Resumes\...\O'Greene_Rick G.pdf`. When I try to open the file using PDF.js I get an error saying `Message: Unexpected server response (0) while retrieving PDF "http://shared_directory/Uploads/Resumes/.../O/"`.

#### javascript

```
 $('.file').on('click touchend', function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        if ($(this).hasClass('disabled'))
            return;
        var path = $(this).data('path').replace(/'/g, "\\'").replace("\\\\", "http://").replace("@pdfFolder", "Uploads");
```

#### cshtml

```
 foreach (var file in combinedFiles.OrderBy(f=> Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(f)).Where(f => Path.GetFileName(f).ToUpper().ToCharArray()[0] == letter))
 {
    <li class="file" data-path="@file" data-lastname="@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_').Last() " data-name="@Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Split('_').First() ">@Truncate(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file).Replace("_", ", "), 27)</li>
 }
```

#### generated html item

```
<li class="file" data-path="\\shared_directory\PDFs\Resumes\O'Greene_Rick G.pdf" data-lastname="Rick G " data-name="O'Greene ">O'Greene, Rick G</li>
```

Comment: Timing issue perhaps. It looks like you're doing the replacing at the wrong point in time. You should replace in your cshtml before it's rendered.

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I tried that using `data-path="@file.Replace("'", "\\'")"` but it didn't help

Comment: can you give me a raw example of a `@file` value?

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama `\\shared_directory\PDFs\Resumes\O'Greene_Rick G.pdf`

Comment: I'm thinking the replace wouldn't work whether client or server side; you should perhaps look at the lib you're using as there might be an option to escape the path you're giving it or a (known) bug

Comment: you could also try replacing on the server side with the HTML entity for single quote `&apos;`

Comment: @TheBeardedLlama I've tried that. When the file is render it is intercepted as a literal string so the file can't be found

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115337/discussion-between-the-bearded-llama-and-antarr-byrd).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to resolve it by replacing `'` with `%27`.

```
data-path="@file.Replace("'","%27")"
```

Comment: got there in the end! :)